# Pass text value to another php file using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have written a code that contain a text box and submit button. When I hit the enter with text box value it should go to another page(q.php) using ajax, and it should return values from there to here(home.php)
here is my code. (home.php)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<script>
function myFunction(str) {
  if (str=="") {
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
  xmlhttp.open("GET","q.php?q="+str,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <form onsubmit="return myFunction(document.getElementById('fname'))">
  Enter name: <input type="text"id="fname" name="fname">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

My next page(q.php)

```
<?php
 $q = $_GET['q'];
 echo $q."Some Content from this page";
 ?>
```

Comment: OK, so what is your question?

Comment: i dont get any answer. but what i'm expecting is "txtHint" id should be replaced with the values from q.php

Comment: Right now, `function myFunction(str)` is expecting to be passed a string, but you're passing it an html element object, since the result of `.getElementById()` is an element object.

Comment: There are many, many, many problems with this code. Which one do you want us to solve? We won't re-write the whole thing for you.

Comment: Peoples are mad,sick and animals who are down-voting without telling why they down-voted? why not "stack" puts some restriction on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is using `html+jquery+php`:-

```
<html>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script><!-- add jquery library -->
<form method="post">
Enter name: <input type="text"id="fname" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class= "abc">
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
 </body>
 </html>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ //when your page is rendered completly
    $('.abc').click(function(e){ //when you click on submit button this function will run
        e.preventDefault();//to prevent normal submission of form
        if($('#fname').val() !== ''){ //check name field have some value
            $.post('q.php',{'q':$('#fname').val()},function( data ){ //send value to post request in ajax to the php page
                $('#txtHint').html(data); //print the response coming from php page to the result div inside your html code
            });
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

And in php file:-

```
<?php
 $q = $_POST['q'];
 echo $q."Some Content from this page";
 ?>
```

Comment: Peoples are mad,sick and animals who are down-voting without telling why they down-voted?